# Entry Point Not Found - VS2019 OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, nsight

I'm using C++ through Visual Studio 2019. I was running my compiled *.exe files with no problems until I did a mistake reinstalling CUDA and insight, and then repairing Visual Studio.

Although there is no problem with the build, I'm now constantly getting the following error:

[image]

I uninstalled Visual Studio 2019, CUDA, and OpenCV, and reinstalled them again, and I'm keeping getting the same error.

Comment: This usually means there is a dll conflict. In that the import library you linked to does not match the dll found in the path.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm new to C++, so can you help me about how I can investigate and solve this. Can this be solved for example by installing opencv-4.1 instead of opencv-4.3?

Comment: It can be solved by being consistent. The easiest way is to make sure there is only 1 version of opencv installed on your PC. And use that version when you link your application to the import libraries and use the headers.

Comment: I already have one version installed, which is referred to in the message box (4.3.0). So, what might be other reasons for this? opencv_imgcodecs430.dll is already in the correct location, and I already included its folder in the path variable. I was trying to install opencv using vcpkg, but the installation failed due to CUDA incompatibility. Can this be the reason? Should I remove vcpkg, and remove its path from the PATH variable? Should I reinstall opencv? Also, before opencv-4.3, opencv-4.1 was installed, but it's completely removed now (both the folder, and the system variable).

Comment: ***Can this be the reason?*** Yes, make sure the dlls from that install are not in your path. Also make sure you are not using the headers from vcpkg. You may want to recompile your application / do a clean build.

Comment: Thank you very much @drescherjm. I removed vcpkg and its environment variables. I also removed all the environment variables and folders of the previous installations. Then, I reinstalled opencv-4.3.0, and everything is working fine now. How can I mark your comments as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message in the picture usually means there is a `dll` conflict between the import library you linked to and the `dll` that was found when windows searched for the matching dll. One such place windows searches is all the folders of the `PATH` environment variable.

It was mentioned in the comments that you attempted to build opencv using vcpkg but did not end up using it because of a cuda conflict. If any part of the `dlls` or import libraries for this opencv build are being used by your code or the `dlls` for opencv are in a folder in the `PATH` environment variable this could cause the problem you have in this question.

My advice is to remove any opencv dlls, headers and import libraries from the `vcpkg` install

```
vcpkg remove opencv4
```

can solve this. Or if you don't need `vcpkg` at all you can remove the binary folders for `vcpkg` from your windows `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I did what you recommended, and then reinstalled opencv-4.3.0, and everything is OK now.